# Custom URI validator doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm first time trying to play with exceptions and custom validators.
When I put this `begin ... end` into seperate file it works, but for my simple test in rspec it does not.

Here's my model's url validation:

```
  validates_each :url do |record,attr,value|
    begin
      !!URI.parse(value)
    rescue URI::InvalidURIError
      record.errors.add(attr, 'invalid url format')
    end
  end
```

rspec ( I get valid here, should be invalid):

```
describe Entry do
  before do
    @entry = Entry.new(title: "Post Title", url: "http://google.com", content: "lorem ipsum")
  end

  subject {@entry}
  it {should be_valid}

  (other tests)

  describe "when url has wrong format" do
    it "should be invalid" do
      invalid_urls = %w[^net.pl p://yahoo.com]
      invalid_urls.each do |url|
        @entry.url = url
        @entry.should_not be_valid
      end
    end
  end

end
```

I put it in seperate file apps/validators/uri_format_validator.rb

```
class UriFormatValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record,attribute,value)
    URI.parse(value)
  rescue URI::InvalidURIError
    record.errors[attribute] << "is not an URL format"
  end
end
```

and still it doesn't work, it's funny cause I tried it with seperate file, and it works fine outputs FALSE for bad urls :

```
require 'uri'

begin
  URI.parse("http://onet!!t.pl")
rescue URI::InvalidURIError
  puts "FALSE"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe a custom validator must subclass `ActiveModel::EachValidator`, having a `validate_each` method e.g.

```
class AllGoodValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(object, attribute, value)
    if <some-test-that-fails-the-validation>
      object.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is not all good")
    end
  end
end
```

which can then be used in your model along with other regular validations, like

```
  validates :something, :presence => true, :all_good => true
```

Comment: Two things: 1) depending on where you put the custom validator, e.g. perhaps in `apps/lib` you might need to restart the rails server, and 2) run `rails console' and create a new Entry instance, add a bogus URL and `save` the instance -- that isolates out the test itself as a possible cause.